# Cursor stays on left of text box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to tweak a widget that loads from Javascript. I'm using jQuery to re-style it.

It has a textbox that is behaving strangely. The cursor stays on the left side of the box and as the user types the text flows to the right. Clicking in the text makes the cursor behave normally.

Does anybody know what might be causing this? I've tried changing the "direction" property but it doesn't help.

Thanks

Comment: Put your code on jsfiddle so your problem can be diagnosed

Answer (score 0):

i think your css having text-align:right

try this

```
      text-align:left !important
```

Comment: I've played with text-align and it doesn't help the problem.